# Potential Energy of a System of Point Charges

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, potential, potential-energy

Is the potential energy of an isolated system of point charges placed in a bounded space in equilibrium necessarily zero?

[image: a configuration of three particles at equilibrium]

Comment: Usually potential energy is defined with an arbitrary constant. With a system of charges in equilibrium I think that potential energy is just minimized locally in the configuration space.

Comment: How can a system of point charges be in equilibrium?

Comment: @my2cts Place q, -q/4, q in straight line, -q/4 at distance d from both

Comment: @Rob if set potential energy at infinity equal to zero then can we say that Potential energy of the system in equilibrium is equal to zero?

Comment: yes the potential energy would be zero.

Comment: You can set the potential energy at infinity to be a *constant* (so it doesn't affect the spatial derivatives that gives the components of the force associated to it) that is exacly the opposite of the potential energy value in this situation of (unstable?) equilibrium

Comment: Please, do not post pictures. Type the question instead (and using MathJax for formulae).  There are many reasons, including facilitation for algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well.  Use a more formal language as well. Thank you.